# Silverlight plugin dissapearing in Firefox when the body has transform: scale

Tags: css, silverlight, firefox

I am embedding a Silverlight like this (Made a simplified project for testing, thus the inline styles):

```
<body style="transform: scale(1)">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
    <div style="width: 255px; height: 54px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 500px;">
        <div id="silverlightControlHost" style="height: 54px; width: 255px;">
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight" width="255px" height="54px">
                <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightEmbeddedTest.xap" />
                <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                <param name="background" value="white" />
                <param value="true" name="windowless" />
                <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Now, I need to have windowless = false for performance reasons, but if I put transform: scale(1), all silverlight plugins dissapear (No matter if it's a simple project or a large silverlight plugin). The project I am using the plugin in uses transform: scale.

IE and Chrome work fine with this.

Anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this while debugging a similar but seemingly unrelated issue. I have sort of the reverse case (a Silverlight OOB app with a WebBrowser control in it hosting an html page). I was trying to use css animations to transform the scale from 0 -> 1 and noticed the element would disappear at 1 and never display again. I ended up switching to use opacity for my animation but I also tested transform:scale(1.00001) which seemed to work.